# Node.js Express: handle requests when users search for .html files directly

Tags: node.js, express, server

I'm having trouble handling requests where a user requests the URL of an HTML file. For example, if the user searches localhost:8080/profile - it will redirect them to a login page if they aren't logged in, however if they search for localost:8080/profile.html it will always take them to profile.html. 
I essentially want to be able to handle requests when they search directly for HTML files. 
When I try to handle using express with:

```
app.get("/profile", function(req, res) {
    // Handle req here
}
```

or

```
app.get("/profile.html", function(req, res) {
    // Handle req here
}
```

neither of these are called when the user searches /profile.html.

All html pages are stored in /public/ and below is the code relating to the setup of the express server.

```
let express = require("express");
let https = require("https");
let path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let fs2 = require("fs");
let httpsOptions = {
    cert : fs2.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'SSL', 'server.cert')),
    key : fs2.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'SSL', 'server.key'))
}

let port = 3443;
let root = "./public"

let server = express();
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(session({secret:"qwertyuiop", resave:false, saveUninitialized:true}));
var staticPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public');
server.use(express.static(staticPath));

start();

async function start() {
    try {
        https.createServer(httpsOptions, server).listen(port, function() {
            console.log('[SERVER] STATUS: Express HTTPS server on listening on port 3443');
        });

    }
    catch (err) { console.log(err); process.exit(1); }
}
```

Comment: Are you using [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) anywhere?

Comment: ````var staticPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public');
    app.use(express.static(staticPath));````

Comment: You should edit your question to include that code and also any more relevant code about the initial setup of your express server. Another question: Is profile.html and all the other html pages you're trying to access located in your public directory?

Comment: Yes they are. I'll update the question now.

Comment: Is it a requirement that those html files be located in that folder? If not, move them somewhere else so that they're not being served as static assets. If so, try moving your `app.get('/profile.html'...` to ***before*** your call to `app.use(express.static...)`.

Comment: I think this is where my lack of understanding of express.static is letting me down. I tried moving the ````app.use(express.static...)```` call to the bottom of my file, but that seems to have broken the css (which i understand *should* be static). I may try rearranging my file system now.